# Force Relative DIV acknowledge his absolute DIV children

Tags: html, css

I got a problem in which my DIV which is `position:relative` doesn't acknowledge his `position:absolute` children. Therefore it causes a problem which the next `position:relative` div is showing at the incorrect spot.

CSS:

```
#header{
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    width:740px;
    outline:2px solid black
}

#header #logo{
    position:absolute;
    width:218px;
    height:69px;
    background-image:url('../images/Logo.png');
    top:15px;
    left:30px;
    text-indent: -999px;
    overflow:hidden !important;
}

#header #logo a{
    width:218px;
    height: 69px;
}

#header h1{
    color:#437297;
    font-size:26px;
    font-weight: normal;
    position:absolute;
    top:25px;
    right:15px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

/* content */

#content{
    position: :relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:1024px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    min-height:10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo"><a href="#">some text</a></div>
    <h1>My Page</h1>
</div>

<div id="content">

</div>
```

To demonstrate the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/qBbYR/

The problem is, the BLACK outlined DIV is the Header DIV which should be at the top of the page, and the RED outlined DIV is the CONTENT DIV which should be right after the HEADER DIV.

As you can see, the header DIV ignores it's children because they are positioned absolute, and that causes design problems.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: The whole point of having mandatory code tags is so that you produce a good quality question that doesn't have users like me downvoting it. Don't explain your code in the JSFiddle - _post it in your question too_

Comment: The point is that you post your code in your question so people can have a go at solving your problem instead of having to constantly switch between your JSFiddle and your description here on SO

Comment: well, your wish it my command i guess :) check the edited post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute positioning takes elements out of normal flow. If you want them to influence the height of their containers, don't position them.

Use padding, margin, floats and display inline-block instead.

Answer (score 2):

Well, positioned tags are kind of autistic. If you need a container to adjust to its children's dimensions, you have two choices:

1. Explicitly set container dimensions; or
2. Make children not-positioned (better IMO).

Comment: I see, so using the position is only when the dimensions are irrelative

Comment: It makes more sense for discrete components. Here you can use positioning for the header and leave its children alone. But maybe it's not a very good use case either. Dialog windows, for example, are a great use case for positioning.